# Calling abstract method of a Abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract-methods

When we call an abstract method of a abstract class from its constructor it returns null.
Why?

```java
abstract class OverloadStaticMethod {
    OverloadStaticMethod(){
        doSubStuff();
    }
    abstract void doSubStuff();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ParentClass();
    }
}
public class ParentClass extends OverloadStaticMethod {
    String s = "Hello world";

    void doSubStuff() {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
null
```

Comment: May I recommend to pay attention to the wording details (sloppy wording often hinders a thorough understanding of concepts): Your abstract method returns nothing, it is declared `void`. It prints "null", coming from the value of the field `s`, which is `null` at that time.

Comment: `new ParentClass();` is calling default constructor of `ParentClass` which **first instruction** (executed before any field of `ParentClass` was initialized) is `super()` which is calling `OverloadStaticMethod` no-argument constructor which is calling `doSubStuff()` which because of polymorpthism (or more precise lage-binding) will execute its implementation from `ParentClass` which is `{ System.out.println(s); }` but at that time `s` is not yet initialized (remember constructor called `super` before any field was initialized).

Comment: That is why it is consider as bad idea to call from constructor methods which (A) can be overridden and (B) are called on current instance like `foo()` or `this.foo()`. BUT it is OK to call methods which (A) can't be overridden like `private` methods, `final` methods or `static` methods OR (B) are called on different objects, for instance passed as parameters like `public MyClass(String name){ if (name.isEmpty()) ..throw some exception.. }`.

Answer (score 1):

Image a field that is defined like this:

```
public class Example {
    private long mark = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

That should make clear that the initializing expression used for a field **is just code**, and code needs to be executed at some point. `"Hello World"` seems like a constant expression, but it doesn't count here (there are rules; in particular, you'd have to make s static and final for it to count as a constant).

The simple explanation is that the line of code that assigns `"Hello World"` to variable `s` has not executed yet, because execution runs in reverse order. When you have `class GrandParent`, `class Parent extends GrandParent` and `class Child extends Parent`, execution is:

- First, GrandParent's initializing expressions and initializers.
- Then, GrandParent's constructor.
- Then, Parent's initializing expressions and initializers.
- Then, Parent's constructor.
- Then, Child's initializing expressions and initializers.
- Then, Child's constructor.

The general fix is to never call overridable methods in any constructor. If you want 'substuff' as a concept, introduce an `init()` method (generally constructors shouldn't do much except do some validation of parameters and store them, this is one of many reasons for why that is the general style advice), or possibly have the result of substuff be passed in as argument to the constructor of the parent class.

NB: Note that 'overload a static method' is an impossibility in java. static methods do not partake in dynamic dispatch at all, and 'overload' as a concept applies to dynamic dispatch. It's like saying you can taste green - it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Admittedly a bit off-topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia (regarding your last sentence..)